# HTML5 getImageData without canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to use getImageData of an image without the canvas? I am wanting to get to pixel color at the mouse position of an image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't.

But getting the imageData can be done with an in-memory canvas, that's fast and easy :

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById('someImageId');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
var theData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

You may keep the `theData` variable so that you don't have to build it at each click.

Note that this won't work if the image comes from another domain (and thus it won't work if you open your html file using `file://` instead of `http://`).

Comment: Interesting... what reason do they have to block getting the image data of an image from another domain?

Comment: This is to prevent XSS attacks. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: But what could possibly happen when trying to retrieve an array of integers?

Comment: So... it's not that `getImageData` might be vulnerable, it's that the security in place to prevent illicit XSS is more of a sledgehammer than a scalpel?

Comment: getImageData add vulnerabilities too. In that case I think they were right to include it.