# HTML5/Javascript code to download a image from the page browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, client-side, imagedownload

I need javascript code to download all images in a web page. Is there a way to do it ?

When the browser loads the page, there might be some images in that page, how to list all of them and download? I mean this should not involve sending request to server. As, the browser has loaded the images, I need to download the images from the browser not the server. How can it be done?

Comment: The standard way is to instruct the browser to download from the server, and letting the browser see that the images are in cache so it doesn't really make a request.

Comment: @Xotic750 ?????

Answer (score 0):

You can get all images and draw it on canvas and then use `getImageData` to get content. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605315/html5-getimagedata-without-canvas)

Comment: No, it still gets the image from the server only.

Comment: I get this error while doing it    Security error : DOM Exception 18  . Why is that ?

Comment: @AbhiRamA take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18-when-i-try-to-set-a-cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the urls or iterate through the images like this

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

var urls = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function (image) {
    if (image.src.length > 0) {
        urls.push(image.src);
    }
});

console.log(urls);
```

A live example is available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/66vAw/)

It is also possible to save images to disk, see t[his example](http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/), but not when they come from another domain.

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/66vAw/7/) that shows the cross domain security error.

[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: It gives an error like Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 . Why is that and how can it be solved ?

Comment: It's a feature. Updated with a couple of links

Comment: So, you are saying that there is no way to download images from another domain programmatically ?

Comment: It can be done from a browser extension as far as I know, but not in the browser window.

Comment: apparently they can't be downloaded from a subdomain either.